# Unable to acess to my Google Apps Dashboard

Tags: google-apps, webmail

I am new to Google Apps Engine. I actually wanted to get a web based mail info@mydomain.com ...the www.mydomain.com was actually registered with GoDaddy. It took me around 30 minutes to set up all ..Google verified my ownership and now I can access my Web mail. But Now When I want to set up my billing, I am unable to find the link...

After I am putting my credentials, the same login page is being showed again and again. It's too confusing for me. Can anyone help me ...How to make payments for that webmail I had set up. Also I didn't created any project for this purpose nor I have any domain purchased from Google. Still it asks... !!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can log into your Google for Work Admin console at admin.google.com.

If you're logged into your email with the account, you can click the gear wheel and select `Manage this domain`. From there, just select the `Billing` section to set it all up. If needed, there's also a `Support` section should you need to contact the Google Support team (24/7).

More details about accessing the Admin console can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076).